# Python dis module weird syntax

Tags: python, exception, raise

I was looking at the dis module code in python 2.7.10 and line 47 has some weird syntax I don't understand:

Raise typeerror, \

I was wondering what the ',\' code does as?

Answer (score 1):

`\` is a [line continuation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) character. It means "this statement continues onto the next line".

If your code looks like,

```
raise Typeerror, \
"expected string, got tuple"
```

That behaves identically to

```
raise Typeerror, "expected string, got tuple"
```